# Incremental loading with MVVM listview in windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, listview, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I have a Listview inside the Pivotitem, Listview ItemsSource binding with the viewmodel collections, its a dynamical collections contains 1000 more items in that, when I use incremental loading for listview its working fine, but inside the pivot with MVVM collection its not working, like when I change the pivot selected index its not working. Any other way to load the listview that could be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of possibilities for your issue,
What exactly happens when you switch the pivot?
Most of the binding problems can be solved by resting the item source of the list, like this:

myList.ItemsSource = null;
myList.ItemsSource = _itemsSource;